# Test all elements in collection for same property value in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there an more succinct / idiomatic way to accomplish the below? I'm not impressed with the double negative in the logic.

e.g. For all items in the collection, `IsPass` is `true`

```
$data = ,@{'IsPass' = $true}, @{'IsPass' = $true}, @{'IsPass' = $true}

if(!$data.IsPass.Contains($false))
{
   Write-Host 'foo'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with your method anyway? I can think of something like this:

```
$data = @{'IsPass' = $true}, @{'IsPass' = $true}, @{'IsPass' = $true}

foreach ($item in $data)
{
    if ($item['IsPass'] -ne $true)
    {
        Write-Host 'foo'
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
$data = @{'IsPass' = $true}, @{'IsPass' = $false}, @{'IsPass' = $true}
$data.IsPass | Where-Object {$_ -ne $true}
```

Comment: There's a double negative in the logic. i.e. "Is there not a false in the collection", weird logic imo. In c#, this would simply be `collection.All(d => d.IsPass)`, which (imo) reads easier.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't behave the same as the example. It will output for every element that doesn't match, rather than for any element.